# Excel SUM of referenced intersect

Tags: excel-formula

How to make the formula in Excel that would sum cels from intersect cells of some range (table) referenced by header column/row.

Of course C7=SUM(D2:F2) but... that's not what I need.

Cell C7 in lower table should calculate sum of all cells from upper table referenced by product defined in cell A7 and week number defined in C6. Number of weeks is not fixed.

[image: Excel example]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the following ARRAY Formula:

```
=SUM(IF($B$1:$G$1=C$6,INDEX($B$2:$B$3,MATCH($A7,$A$2:$A$3,0)):INDEX($G$2:$G$3,MATCH($A7,$A$2:$A$3,0)),0))
```

As is an Array Formula you need to confirm it with `CRTL+SHIFT+ENTER` instead of `ENTER`. See screenshot of a working example:

[image]

The formula works as follows, `INDEX($B$2:$B$3,MATCH($A7,$A$2:$A$3,0))` provides the first cell of the row that's going to be the SumRange (`B2` for Prod1) and `INDEX($G$2:$G$3,MATCH($A7,$A$2:$A$3,0))` provides the last cell of the SumRange (`G2` for Prod1) so if we replace them for the result, we get `SUM(IF(B1:G1=C6,B2:G2,0))`.

Comment: Is it possible to achieve the same thing using `=SUMIFS()` function?

Comment: The Product constraint is not a row like the amounts and the amounts are not a row but a matrix, so you can't use it. It would work if your data was presented in 3 columns (product, week and amount)